# how do i add a shortcut to homescreen in #materinova launcher?

Tags: updates, home-screen-shortcuts, nova-launcher

I downloaded the latest nova launcher named #materinova.15 , in its previous versions I could add a shortcut by holding a blank space in the home screen and chose shortcuts, but in the latest release I can't find any options for adding shortcuts, though I can put apps  on the home screen by going to app drawer and holding and dragging the app to the home screen, but I can't find the shortcuts. Please help, this is my favorite app so don't want to leave it for this little bad thing?

Comment: What do you mean by shortcuts? Do you mean those shortcuts that you pick from the widget picker?

Comment: The material redesign of Nova launcher is still in beta, and therefore may be missing features.  If you absolutely need to use shortcuts now, I suggest reverting to the latest stable version.  For that you either leave the beta test via the [G+ community](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.teslacoilsw.launcher/join%EF%BB%BF), or simply download the APK from [here](https://plus.google.com/+KevinBarry/posts/4U8TPBMFSkw).

Answer (score 4):

That's because they are sorted alongside all the widgets. That's not very intuitive but at least they're here!

Comment: Wow, you're right. That kind of sucks, very confusing. I also hate the new widget list in general: it is much slower to navigate than the old list, where each item took up much less space.

Answer (score 0):

1) open the "nova action" widget
2) locate the app you want to add to the home screen and longpress on it.

The "nova action" widget is the 1st one in the nova widget drawer, if its not on your home screen you need to add it 1st